# How to set a proper context for a ListBox ItemTemplate property in a custom user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datacontext

Here is my ListBox Custom control: `UCListBox`. The `MainLabel` is the property I have issues with. It is used as a "label" for a ListBox item:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCListBox}}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCListBox}}"
         >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCListBox}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class UCListBox : UserControl
{
    public UCListBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(UCListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(UCListBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public string MainLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MainLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainLabelProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MainLabel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MainLabel", typeof(string), typeof(UCListBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    }
```

Here I try to use my custom control in a window:

```
<local:UCListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Participants}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParticipant}"
    MainLabel ="{Binding NameShort1}"
/>
```

I get a binding error:

```
Property "NameShort1 is not found for WindowEditCaseVM.
```

The context of the `MainLabel` property is my View Model like the rest of the properties and not the context of a ListBox item. How do I fix the context of my custom control's property to display listbox items correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to select a property of the item class (i.e. the element type of the Participants collection) as the source of a Binding? Take a look at how the ItemsControl's DisplayMemberPath works. Besides that, you could save a lot of code if you derive your control from ListBox instead of UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for response, but as I understand DisplayMemberPath only provides simple listbox items with a single displayed property and I wanted to configure more complex datatemplates for my listboxes in the future if possible.

Comment: That's why I said you should look at the way it works, not to use it. It is still unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve. I ask again, is MainLabel supposed to select a property of the item class? And how would the DataTemplate show anything else beyond what is selected by MainLabel? What you have right now just looks like a re-invention of DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: @Clemens I wanted to make a data template with 2-3 properties, something like `MainLabel`, `SecondaryLabel`, `TertiaryLabel`, so when I use my UserControl I just bind several item class properties to them and get structured formatting.

Comment: And what stops you from using a regular ListBox with an appropriate ItemTemplate? You could simply declare different DataTemplate resources for different item types, even so that they would be chosen automatically.

Comment: @Clemens I'll try it out and will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that helped me to solve my problem with help of @Clemens was to make the DataTemplate into a resource and define a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype?view=net-5.0) property for it.

First, define a namespace, containing my `Participant` class in the head of my UserControl:

```
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:DocConstructor.BusinessModel"
```

Then define the resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Participant}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameShort1}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CaseStatusType.Description}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Full code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DocConstructor.UserControls.UCListBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocConstructor.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:DocConstructor.BusinessModel"
>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Participant}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameShort1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CaseStatusType.Description}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCListBox}}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCListBox}}"            
             >
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Be aware that this UserControl is entirely redundant. Move the DataTemplate resource(s) to Application.Resources in App.xaml or to Window.Resources and write `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Participants}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParticipant}"/>`.